# How can I push the newest version of my project to the repo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, github, system-administration

I'm working on a small React project and have pushed its old version to the GitHub a couple days ago to this repo: [Old repo](https://github.com/Leocete/React_test-project)

Since that time, I've made multiple changes to my project, so I decided to create a new repo and push the latest version of the app there.

The problem is that the old version of the project has been pushed to my new repo, I don't understand why. Can you help me to resolve this?

**Please, tell me what is the mistake - why I'm pushing the old version of my app that even not exists on my computer?**

Here is a link to my new repo: [New repo](https://github.com/Leocete/react-test-app)

Steps I've made in Windows Powershell to push the project to new repo:

- git init
- git add -A
- git commit -m 'Added my project'
- git remote rm origin
- git remote add origin https://github.com/Leocete/react-test-app.git
- git push -u origin master

Comment: why don't you make a local copy of your new project at some other location on your system and then try git init

Comment: yes, I've tried - don't work

Comment: What does `git status` say? can you please add that?

Comment: [Status](http://joxi.ru/52aaBE9I47ZzX2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're still in the middle of a rebase.
It stopped rebasing since there was/are conflicts.

Please fix your conflicts.
Then run `git add -A && git commit -am "your message here"`
After that you need to `continue` your rebase by using: `git rebase --continue`

If all went well you rebased your branch and are able to push the changes with `git push -f`. This will **force** push your branch since you've diversed from remote.. as @vincentm already said be warned since you're changing the history line.

Comment: When I want to rebase, I received the following message : [Error](http://joxi.ru/KAgxBdDT4Lew8r)

Comment: Should I add a new origin here?

Comment: As said you have uncomitted changes.. execute this oneline to do it all: `git add -A && git commit -am "Changes" && git rebase --continue && git push -f` what these commando's do is explained in my answere

Comment: Did this fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `--force` to overwrite the remote code. ( `git push --force origin master` )

Use it with caution (your repo is new, so i think it's not a problem, but avoid it on a repo with hundreds of commits :-) ).

Comment: I've tried it, but old files have added: https://github.com/Leocete/new-react-app